# JS when i add new row in table the previous one is cleared

Tags: javascript

I have specific problem. When I press button "Dodaj produkt", the values of inputs that have been inserted, are cleared. For example, fields: name, count, price_netto, vat_rate, price_brutto, summary_entity. Even if they're filled, after I press the button the values are default. I don't know why does this happens but I hope that someone will explain it to me.

```js
var id_count = 1;
var price_summary = 0;

function delete_product(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).remove();
}

function change_brutto(id) {
  var netto = replace_dots(document.getElementById("price_netto" + id));
  var vat = replace_dots(document.getElementById("vat_rate" + id));
  var count = replace_dots(document.getElementById("count" + id));
  if (vat > 0) {
    vat = vat / 100;
    vat += 1;
    var calc = netto * vat;
    document.getElementById("price_brutto" + id).value = Math.round((calc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    calc = calc * count;
    document.getElementById("summary" + id).value = Math.round((calc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  } else if (vat == "" || vat == 0) {
    document.getElementById("vat_rate" + id).value = "0";
    document.getElementById("price_brutto" + id).value = netto;
    document.getElementById("summary" + id).value = netto * count;
  } else {
    alert("Wpisz poprawną stawkę VAT");
  }
}

function change_netto(id) {
  var brutto = replace_dots(document.getElementById("price_brutto" + id));
  var vat = replace_dots(document.getElementById("vat_rate" + id));
  if (vat > 0) {
    vat = vat / 100;
    vat += 1;
    var calc = brutto / vat;
    document.getElementById("price_netto" + id).value = Math.round((calc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  } else if (vat == "" || vat == 0) {
    document.getElementById("vat_rate" + id).value = "0";
    document.getElementById("price_netto" + id).value = brutto;
  } else {
    alert("Wpisz poprawną stawkę VAT");
  }
}

function replace_dots(string) {
  newString = string.value.replace(",", ".");
  return newString;
}

function vat_changed(id) {
  if (document.getElementById("price_netto" + id).value != "") {
    change_brutto(id);
  } else if (document.getElementById("price_brutto" + id).value != "") {
    change_netto(id);
  }
}

function count_changed(id) {
  var count = replace_dots(document.getElementById("count" + id));
  var brutto = replace_dots(document.getElementById("price_brutto" + id));
  var summ = document.getElementsByName("summary_entity[]");
  document.getElementById("summary" + id).value = brutto * count;
  for (var i = 0; i < summ.length; i++) {
    var val = summ[i];
    price_summary += parseFloat(val.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = price_summary;
}

function summary() {

}
window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("add_product");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    id_count += 1;
    document.getElementById("products_table").innerHTML +=
      "<tr id='" + id_count + "'>\
         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name' id='name" + id_count + "' placeholder='Nazwa produktu'></td>\
         <td><input type='number' class='form-control' onchange='count_changed(" + id_count + ")' name='count' id='count" + id_count + "' value='1' placeholder='Liczba produktów'></td>\
         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' onchange='change_brutto(" + id_count + ")' name='price_netto' id='price_netto" + id_count + "' oninput='netto_changed()' value='0.00' placeholder='Cena netto'></td>\
         <td class='input-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' onchange='vat_changed(" + id_count + ")' name='vat_rate' id='vat_rate" + id_count + "' value='23' placeholder='Stawka VAT'>\
           <span class='input-group-addon'>%</span>\
         </td>\
         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price_brutto' id='price_brutto" + id_count + "' oninput='brutto_changed()' value='0.00' placeholder='Stawka brutto'></td>\
         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='summary_entity[]' id='summary" + id_count + "' value='0.00' readonly></td>\
         <td><button type='button' onclick='delete_product(" + id_count + ")' class='btn btn-alert'>Usuń</button></td>\
       </tr>";
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<table id="products_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Nazwa produktu</th>
    <th style="width: 7%;">Liczba produktów</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Cena jednostkowa netto</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Stawka VAT</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Cena jednostkowa brutto</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Wartość końcowa brutto</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Akcje</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name1" placeholder="Nazwa produktu"></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="count_changed(1)" name="count" id="count1" value="1" placeholder="Liczba produktów"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_brutto(1)" name="price_netto" id="price_netto1" value="0.00" placeholder="Cena netto"></td>
    <td class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="vat_changed(1)" name="vat_rate" id="vat_rate1" value="23" placeholder="Stawka VAT">
      <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_netto(1)" name="price_brutto" id="price_brutto1" value="0.00" placeholder="Cena brutto"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="summary_entity[]" id="summary1" value="0.00" readonly></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="delete_product(1)" class="btn btn-alert">Usuń</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 60%; text-align: right;">Razem do zapłaty: </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;" name="summary" id="summary"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="add_product" class="btn btn-success">Dodaj produkt</button>
```

Comment: When you click the addProduct button you're replacing the entire HTML of `products_table`.

Comment: Thanks. I used insertAdjacentHTML instead and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

## The problem is:

your `<tr>` tags must be put inside `<tbody>`. Because you are missing it, so whenever you add a new `<tr>`, new `<tbody>` will automatically added and warpped around the `<tr>`. But one `<table>`, only have 1 `<tbody>`, adding more than 1 causing the entire table to reload.

## Solution:

Create a `<tbody>` tag inside your table, give it an ID.
Whenever you want to insert new row, insert into that `<tbody>` instead

```
<table>
<tbody id="products_table">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your solution did not work. I had to use insertAdjacentHTML instead of innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Leo's answer is probably the best you should do, but I found an other way.

I used the insertRow and insertCell functions that append things without reloading the table.

Here's a working example (you can run it using the run code snippet at the bottom):

```js
var id_count = 1;
var price_summary = 0;
function delete_product(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).remove();
}

function change_brutto(id) {
  var netto = replace_dots(document.getElementById('price_netto' + id));
  var vat = replace_dots(document.getElementById('vat_rate' + id));
  var count = replace_dots(document.getElementById('count' + id));
  if (vat > 0) {
    vat = vat / 100;
    vat += 1;
    var calc = netto * vat;
    document.getElementById('price_brutto' + id).value =
      Math.round((calc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    calc = calc * count;
    document.getElementById('summary' + id).value =
      Math.round((calc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  } else if (vat == '' || vat == 0) {
    document.getElementById('vat_rate' + id).value = '0';
    document.getElementById('price_brutto' + id).value = netto;
    document.getElementById('summary' + id).value = netto * count;
  } else {
    alert('Wpisz poprawną stawkę VAT');
  }
}

function change_netto(id) {
  var brutto = replace_dots(document.getElementById('price_brutto' + id));
  var vat = replace_dots(document.getElementById('vat_rate' + id));
  if (vat > 0) {
    vat = vat / 100;
    vat += 1;
    var calc = brutto / vat;
    document.getElementById('price_netto' + id).value =
      Math.round((calc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  } else if (vat == '' || vat == 0) {
    document.getElementById('vat_rate' + id).value = '0';
    document.getElementById('price_netto' + id).value = brutto;
  } else {
    alert('Wpisz poprawną stawkę VAT');
  }
}

function replace_dots(string) {
  newString = string.value.replace(',', '.');
  return newString;
}

function vat_changed(id) {
  if (document.getElementById('price_netto' + id).value != '') {
    change_brutto(id);
  } else if (document.getElementById('price_brutto' + id).value != '') {
    change_netto(id);
  }
}

function count_changed(id) {
  var count = replace_dots(document.getElementById('count' + id));
  var brutto = replace_dots(document.getElementById('price_brutto' + id));
  var summ = document.getElementsByName('summary_entity[]');
  document.getElementById('summary' + id).value = brutto * count;
  for (var i = 0; i < summ.length; i++) {
    var val = summ[i];
    price_summary += parseFloat(val.value);
  }
  document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML = price_summary;
}

function summary() {}
window.onload = function () {
  var btn = document.getElementById('add_product');
  btn.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
      id_count += 1;
      let table = document.getElementById('products_table');
      let row = table.insertRow();
      row.id = id_count;
      let cell0 = row.insertCell();
      cell0.innerHTML =
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name' id='name" +
        id_count +
        "' placeholder='Nazwa produktu'></td>";
      let cell1 = row.insertCell();
      cell1.innerHTML =
        "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' onchange='count_changed(" +
        id_count +
        ")' name='count' id='count" +
        id_count +
        "' value='1' placeholder='Liczba produktów'></td>";
      let cell2 = row.insertCell();
      cell2.innerHTML =
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' onchange='change_brutto(" +
        id_count +
        ")' name='price_netto' id='price_netto" +
        id_count +
        "' oninput='netto_changed()' value='0.00' placeholder='Cena netto'></td>";
      let cell3 = row.insertCell();
      cell3.innerHTML =
        "<td class='input-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' onchange='vat_changed(" +
        id_count +
        ")' name='vat_rate' id='vat_rate" +
        id_count +
        "' value='23' placeholder='Stawka VAT'><span class='input-group-addon'>%</span></td>";
      let cell4 = row.insertCell();
      cell4.innerHTML =
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price_brutto' id='price_brutto" +
        id_count +
        "' oninput='brutto_changed()' value='0.00' placeholder='Stawka brutto'></td>";
      let cell5 = row.insertCell();
      cell5.innerHTML =
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='summary_entity[]' id='summary" +
        id_count +
        "' value='0.00' readonly></td>";
      let cell6 = row.insertCell();
      cell6.innerHTML =
        "<td><button type='button' onclick='delete_product(" +
        id_count +
        ")' class='btn btn-alert'>Usuń</button></td>";
    },
    false
  );
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="products_table" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th >Nazwa produktu</th>
        <th style="width: 7%;">Liczba produktów</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Cena jednostkowa netto</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Stawka VAT</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Cena jednostkowa brutto</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Wartość końcowa brutto</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Akcje</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name1" placeholder="Nazwa produktu"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="count_changed(1)" name="count" id="count1" value="1" placeholder="Liczba produktów"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_brutto(1)" name="price_netto" id="price_netto1" value="0.00" placeholder="Cena netto"></td>
        <td class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="vat_changed(1)" name="vat_rate" id="vat_rate1" value="23" placeholder="Stawka VAT">
            <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_netto(1)" name="price_brutto" id="price_brutto1" value="0.00" placeholder="Cena brutto"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="summary_entity[]" id="summary1" value="0.00" readonly></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="delete_product(1)" class="btn btn-alert">Usuń</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 60%; text-align: right;">Razem do zapłaty: </td>
        <td style="text-align: left;" name="summary" id="summary"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <button type="button" id="add_product" class="btn btn-success">Dodaj produkt</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nah, Leo solution did not work. I had to use insertAdjacentHTML instead of innerHTML